# FirstorDefault with Multiple && conditions?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have a function that is not working as it should since I cannot implement multiple conditions into FirstorDefault for some reason. I have seen other examples on StackOverflow where people were able to do it, but I cannot. If I just test for && Year or && Org, it works. But when I add the second && statement it does nothing. All of the conditions are true for the data I am sending it and I have confirmed this over and over.

What can I do to make this work?

```
    public partial class Cmp_REC
{
    public int cId { get; set; }
    public int Org { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }

    public virtual Cmp_Accounts Cmp_Accounts { get; set; }
}

public static void DeleteREC(int cId, int Year, int Org)
{
    using (Entities dataContext = new Entities())
    {
        Cmp_REC toDelete = dataContext.Cmp_REC.FirstOrDefault(c => c.cId == cId && c.Org == Org && c.Year == Year);
        if (toDelete != null)
        {
            dataContext.Cmp_REC.Remove(toDelete);
            dataContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check toDelete. Maybe it is null. Can you show your Cmp_REC class pls?

Comment: @Sergey There you go. It works if I just have c => c.cId == cId && c.Org == Org or c => c.cId == cId && c.Year == Year

Comment: That is why I suspect something is going on, syntax-wise.

Comment: You didn' answer the question. Is toDelete is null when you have 3 parameters? Is it null when you have 2 parameters? I am just trying to find a place where the error happens.  Is  it in select or Add.

Comment: It is not null. @Sergey

Comment: If you get a match using 2 of the 3 conditions, does the 3rd condition match? Instead of FirstOrDefault, try (as debugging step) a ToList and inspect that 3rd condition on all results

Comment: Your description of the problem is not very clear. With all of the conditions, does a breakpoint on the line `dataContext.Cmp_REC.Remove(toDelete);` get hit? Is there an exception being raised? "it does nothing" isn't very descriptive. Also, `FirstOrDefault` should only ever be used with an OrderBy clause. If you expect there should be only 0 or 1 row, then use `SingleOrDefault`,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. Apparently, it needed to have the variables listed in the same order as they are sent from the function. It works now.

```
public static void DeleteREC(int cId, int Year, int Org)
{
    using (Entities dataContext = new Entities())
    {
        Cmp_REC toDelete = dataContext.Cmp_REC.FirstOrDefault(c => c.cId == cId  && c.Year == Year && c.Org == Org);
        if (toDelete != null)
        {
            dataContext.Cmp_REC.Remove(toDelete);
            dataContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably you also changed something else, as the order *cannot* be the issue

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Nope. It was the issue. It was sending values in incorrect order. I confirmed it with breakpoints when I was debugging. Sorry, but you are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the record you are going to delete  is different from the records you selected before. And this  record is used by another table Cmp_Accounts  in your db. this is why you  can't delete it . You have to delete all references to this record at first.